# ShellExecute File Not Found Error when files contain apostrophe

Tags: c, winapi, unicode, shellexecute

I currently have a method that uses ShellExecute to open files passed in by the user. Recently it was discovered that when a filename contains an apostrophe (ALT+0146) or Mac simple quote, ShellExecute returns a File Not Found Error. Example filename: "C:\Users\AMS\Documents\te'st.txt"

Code:

```
void sys_ShellExecute( PA_PluginParameters params )
{

LONG_PTR returnValue = 0;
char returnText[255]; // MWD & Mark De Wever #12225
INT_PTR  howToShow;
char *pChar;

char *operation = NULL;
char *file = NULL;
char *parameters = NULL;
char *directory = NULL;

//PA_Unistring *file; // AMS 2/24/14

// Get the function parameters.
operation = getTextParameter(params, 1);
file = getTextParameter(params, 2);
//file = PA_GetStringParameter(params, 2); // AMS 2/24/14
parameters = getTextParameter(params, 3);
directory = getTextParameter(params, 4);
howToShow = PA_GetLongParameter( params, 5 ); 



if ((strcmp(_strlwr(operation), "open")         != 0) &&
     (strcmp(_strlwr(operation),  "explore")    != 0) &&
     (strcmp(_strlwr(operation),  "print")      != 0) &&
     (file == NULL || strlen(file) == 0)) { 
    //strcpy(returnText, "Invalid Operation");
    strncpy(returnText, message->InvalidOperation, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 replaced the line above
}
else if (howToShow > 11) {
    //strcpy(returnText, "Invalid HowToShow Constant");
    strncpy(returnText, message->InvalidShowConstant, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 replaced the line above
}
else
{
    pChar = file; // added 10/28/02 shellExecute wants backslashes
    do {
        if (*pChar == '/') {
            *pChar = '\\';
        }

    } while (*pChar++ != '\0') ;

    pChar = directory;
    do  {
        if (*pChar == '/') { 
            *pChar = '\\';
        }
    } while (*pChar++ != '\0');

    returnValue = (LONG_PTR) ShellExecute(NULL, operation, file, parameters, directory, howToShow);

    strcpy(returnText, "");
    if (returnValue <= 32) { // error occurred
        switch (returnValue)
        {
        case ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND :
            //strcpy(returnText, "File Not Found");     
            strncpy(returnText, message->FileNotFound, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 replaced line above
            break;

        case ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND :
            //strcpy(returnText, "Path Not Found");
            strncpy(returnText, message->PathNotFound, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
            break;

        case ERROR_BAD_FORMAT :
            //strcpy(returnText, ".EXE File is Invalid");       
            strncpy(returnText, message->BadFormat, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
            break;

        case SE_ERR_ACCESSDENIED :
            //strcpy(returnText, "OS Denied Access to File");       
            strncpy(returnText, message->AccessDenied, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
            break;

        case SE_ERR_ASSOCINCOMPLETE  :
            //strcpy(returnText, "File Name Association is Incomplete or Invalid");     
            strncpy(returnText, message->AssocIncomplete, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
            break;

        case SE_ERR_DDEBUSY  :
        case SE_ERR_DDEFAIL   :
            //strcpy(returnText, "DDE Transaction Could Not be Completed");
    strncpy(returnText, message->DDEFail, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
            break;

        case SE_ERR_DDETIMEOUT   :
            //strcpy(returnText, "DDE Request Timed Out");      
            strncpy(returnText, message->DDETimeOut, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
            break;

        case SE_ERR_DLLNOTFOUND    :
            //strcpy(returnText, "DLL Libray Not Found");
    strncpy(returnText, message->DLLNotFound, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
            break;

        case SE_ERR_NOASSOC   :
            //strcpy(returnText, "No Application Associated with File Extenstion");
    strncpy(returnText, message->NoAssoc, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
            break;

        case SE_ERR_OOM :
            //strcpy(returnText, "Insufficient Memory");
    strncpy(returnText, message->OOM, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
            break;

        case SE_ERR_SHARE    :
            //strcpy(returnText, "Sharing Violation Occurred");
    strncpy(returnText, message->ShareViolation, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
            break;

        default:
            //strcpy(returnText, "Unknown error occurred"); 
            strncpy(returnText, message->Default, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
            break;
        }
    }
}

freeTextParameter(operation);
freeTextParameter(file);
freeTextParameter(parameters);
freeTextParameter(directory);

PA_ReturnText( params, returnText, strlen(returnText));
}
```

getTextParameter code:

```
char * getTextParameter(PA_PluginParameters param, short index)
{

char *textValue = NULL;
LONG_PTR textLength = 0;

textLength = PA_GetTextParameter( param, index, 0L ) + 1;

// modified by Mark de Wever on 20060721
   // textLength was always > 0 due to the +1
  // revert change since sys_ShellExecute
  // fails if NULL pointer is returned...
  // So if malloc fails it will crash 4D
  // if(textLength > 1) {
if(textLength > 0) {
    textValue = (char *)malloc(textLength);

    if(textValue != NULL) {

        memset(textValue, 0, textLength);
        textLength = PA_GetTextParameter( param, index, textValue );

    }

}

return textValue;

}
```

PA_GetTextParameter code:

```
LONG_PTR PA_GetTextParameter( PA_PluginParameters params, short index, char* text ) 
{
PA_Unistring            *UnistringText; 
LONG_PTR                length;
char                    *textParameter;


UnistringText = PA_GetStringParameter( params, index);

if(text != 0L){

    textParameter = malloc((UnistringText->fLength + 1) * sizeof(char));
    memset(textParameter, 0, ((UnistringText->fLength + 1) * sizeof(char)));


    wcstombs(textParameter, UnistringText->fString, UnistringText->fLength);
    textParameter[strlen(textParameter)] = '\0';

    strcpy(text, textParameter);

    free (textParameter);

    length = strlen(text);


}else{
    length = UnistringText->fLength;
}

return length;
}
```

I noticed that wcstombs returns the filename without the apostrophe in textParameter and the full filename in UnistringText->fString.

I have tried using ShellExecuteW, ShellExecuteA, setting file to a unicode string, and many other variations and nothing seems to work. Am I missing something? Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Try the [processmoitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) utility. With this program you can monitor which files are opened by which process. It's very powerful and may help you to spot the problem.

Comment: If you call ShellExecuteW passing the filename as a literal unicode string (e.g. `L"C:\\Users\\AMS\\Documents\\te'st.txt"`), does it work?  If so, don't apply any conversion to the original string (`UnistringText->fString`) and it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>ALT+0146</kbd> is Unicode codepoint `U+2019 SINGLE QUOTATION MARK`.  That is not the same as Unicode codepoint `U+0027 APOSTROPHE`.  U+0027 is in the ASCII range so `wcstomb()` will preserve it as-is, but U+2019 is outside of ASCII and thus subject to charset/codepage conversions.  If `wcstombs()` is omitting U+2019 than that usually means Windows' default codepage does not support that particular codepoint.  However, you are also not taking into account that the length of a narrow string can be different than the length of the wide version of the same string, so that might also play a factor.

In any case, since your input parameters are Unicode strings to begin with, you really should be using Uncode API functions (like `ShellExecuteW()`) and not convert the Unicode strings to MBS at all.

```
void sys_ShellExecute( PA_PluginParameters params )
{
    LONG_PTR returnValue;
    char returnText[255]; // MWD & Mark De Wever #12225
    wchar_t *pChar;

    // Get the function parameters.
    wchar_t *operation = getTextParameter(params, 1);
    wchar_t *file = getTextParameter(params, 2);
    wchar_t *parameters = getTextParameter(params, 3);
    wchar_t *directory = getTextParameter(params, 4);
    INT_PTR howToShow = PA_GetLongParameter( params, 5 ); 

    if ((lstrcmpiW(operation, L"open") != 0) &&
       (lstrcmpiW(operation,  L"explore") != 0) &&
       (lstrcmpiW(operation,  L"print") != 0)) {
       strncpy(returnText, message->InvalidOperation, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 replaced the line above
    }
    else if ((file == NULL) || (lstrlenW(file) == 0)) {
       strncpy(returnText, message->InvalidFile, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 replaced the line above
    } 
    else if (howToShow > 11) {
        strncpy(returnText, message->InvalidShowConstant, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 replaced the line above
    }
    else
    {
        pChar = file; // added 10/28/02 shellExecute wants backslashes
        do {
            if (*pChar == L'/') {
                *pChar = L'\\';
            }
        } while (*CharNextW(pChar) != L'\0') ;

        if (directory != NULL) {    
            pChar = directory;
            while (*pChar != L'\0') {
                if (*pChar == L'/') { 
                    *pChar = L'\\';
                }
                pChar = CharNext(pChar);
            }
        }

        returnValue = (LONG_PTR) ShellExecuteW(NULL, operation, file, parameters, directory, howToShow);

        strcpy(returnText, "");
        if (returnValue <= 32) { // error occurred
            switch (returnValue)
            {
                case ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND :
                    strncpy(returnText, message->FileNotFound, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 replaced line above
                    break;

                case ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND :
                    strncpy(returnText, message->PathNotFound, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
                    break;

                case ERROR_BAD_FORMAT :
                    strncpy(returnText, message->BadFormat, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
                    break;

                case SE_ERR_ACCESSDENIED :
                    strncpy(returnText, message->AccessDenied, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
                    break;

                case SE_ERR_ASSOCINCOMPLETE  :
                    strncpy(returnText, message->AssocIncomplete, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
                    break;

                case SE_ERR_DDEBUSY  :
                case SE_ERR_DDEFAIL   :
                    strncpy(returnText, message->DDEFail, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
                    break;

                case SE_ERR_DDETIMEOUT   :
                    strncpy(returnText, message->DDETimeOut, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
                    break;

                case SE_ERR_DLLNOTFOUND    :
                    strncpy(returnText, message->DLLNotFound, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
                    break;

                case SE_ERR_NOASSOC   :
                    strncpy(returnText, message->NoAssoc, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
                    break;

                case SE_ERR_OOM :
                    strncpy(returnText, message->OOM, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
                    break;

                case SE_ERR_SHARE    :
                    strncpy(returnText, message->ShareViolation, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
                    break;

                default:
                    strncpy(returnText, message->Default, 255); // Mark De Wever #12225 Replaced line above
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    freeTextParameter(operation);
    freeTextParameter(file);
    freeTextParameter(parameters);
    freeTextParameter(directory);

    PA_ReturnText( params, returnText, strlen(returnText));
}
```

```
wchar_t * getTextParameter(PA_PluginParameters param, short index)
{
    wchar_t *textValue = NULL;
    LONG_PTR textLength = PA_GetTextParameter( param, index, 0L ) + 1;

    // modified by Mark de Wever on 20060721
    // textLength was always > 0 due to the +1
    // revert change since sys_ShellExecute
    // fails if NULL pointer is returned...
    // So if malloc fails it will crash 4D
    // if(textLength > 1) {
    if (textLength > 0) {
        textValue = (wchar_t *) malloc(textLength * sizeof(wchar_t));
        if(textValue != NULL) {
            memset(textValue, 0, textLength * sizeof(wchar_t));
            if (textLength > 1) {
                PA_GetTextParameter( param, index, textValue );
            }
        }
    }

    return textValue;
}

void freeTextParameter(wchar_t *param)
{
    free(param);
}
```

```
LONG_PTR PA_GetTextParameter( PA_PluginParameters params, short index, wchar_t* text ) 
{
    PA_Unistring            *UnistringText; 
    LONG_PTR                length;

    UnistringText = PA_GetStringParameter( params, index);
    if (UnistringText != NULL) {
        length = UnistringText->fLength;
    } else {
        length = 0;
    }

    if (text != NULL) {
        if (UnistringText != NULL) {
            memcpy(text, UnistringText->fString, length * sizeof(wchar_t));
        }
        text[length] = L'\0';
    }

    return length;
}
```